# Navigation graph move to root fragment when minimizing app

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I am facing an issue with my app. When I am minimizing the app and open it again. The recent fragment change to root fragment.

For Example :
I move from **FragmentA > FragmentB > FragmentC**
minimize the app and comes back
now FragmentA is displaying.

I want to display FragmentC after coming back.

Comment: Can you add you code also?

Comment: its too big i cant add all the code

Comment: have you overridden the onPause or onStop methods?

Comment: No, i didnt use